# Quotation marks shortage when from python dumping JSON and parse it within js2py environment

Tags: javascript, python, json

So please do not ask me why, but I would like to do the following.

I would like to define a javascript function as a string within a dictionary in the python language. Then I would like to execute this function in a browserless javascript environment. The defined function already contains two types of quotation marks.

My attempt so far:

```
import json
import js2py

js_function = """
var convertDateTime = function (s, key, input) {
    console.log('    - Executing "convertDateTime".');
    s[key] = input.dateTime.toISOString().split('Z')[0].replace('T', '');
};
"""
f = {'function': js_function}
```

result of f (which is not code...):

```
{'function': '\nvar convertDateTime = function (s, key, input) >{\n    
console.log(\'    - Executing "convertDateTime".\');\n    
s[key] = input.dateTime.toISOString().split(\'Z\')[0].replace(\'T\', \' 
\');\n};\n'}
```

Now, first of all, I would like to convert this to a string representing correct JSON and then convert it to a javascript object in the js2py environment. In order to let it work in js2py env with the JSON.parse I need to remove the \n, \" and ' marks. If I do not do it, I get the message:

> js_env.execute("spec = JSON.parse('"+spec+"');")
>
> JsException: SyntaxError: Could not parse JSON string - Invalid syntax

I tried every quotation combination with the JSON.parse there is and found this single working combination.

```
spec = json.dumps(f).replace("\\n", "").replace('\\"', "").replace("'", "`")
js_env = js2py.EvalJs()
js_env.execute("spec = JSON.parse('"+spec+"');")
```

The problem, however, is that when evaluating this function, js2py does not support ` and I couldn't find a way to let it work with js2py 6 stuff, because I couldn't find function in js2py which can create an environment supporting JavaScript 6.

```
js_env.execute("eval(spec['function'])")
```

Error message:

> js_env.execute("eval(spec['function'])")
>
> NotImplementedError: TemplateLiteral is not supported!

Restrictions:

- The js function which can be anything, but will only contain simple
  js code must end up as a string in a python dict somewhere.
- I should be able to execute the js function in a browserless js
  environment.
- python version 2.7.13

I hope somebody could help me forward,

Comment: What about just `js_env.execute("spec = "+spec+";")`?

Comment: Thanks, in thissimple example is does work! I guess after pythons json.dumps it doesn't need to be parsed again in JavaScript? I am now trying it on the real example.

Comment: JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation - the syntax originates from JS and valid JSON should automatically be valid JS.

Comment: Also the real example now works. I am very happy. Not sure what I should do here, delete this post because the question is stupid?

Comment: I'll make an answer. I don't think this is a stupid question and someone else might find it while searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

```
js_env.execute("spec = "+spec+";")
```

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation - the syntax originates from JS and valid JSON should automatically be valid JS. Therefore JSON can be directly inserted into JavaScript code and just work.